# Rails - How to get total of params

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `Restaurant` model.

Meeting model has_many :vouchers (integer)

Let's say I have 10 vouchers left, when I spent all vouchers until 0, it can be topped up to 10 more vouchers by admin (manually using restaurant form).

In Restaurant form:

```
<% if current_user.admin? %>
    <%= form_for @restaurant %>
        <%= f.number_field :voucher %>
        <%= f.submit, value: 'Top Up Voucher' %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In user show:

```
You have <%= @user.voucher %> vouchers left
```

My question is how to get total of voucher?

Ex: I have topped up voucher 3 times.

```
(3x10 vouchers) = **total 30 vouchers (this is what I want to get)**
```

I tried

```
<%= @user.voucher.size %>
```

and

```
<%= @user.voucher.count %>
```

but they both didn't work.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: `User.voucherS.count` You missed the s since you relation is `has_many :vouchers`. Although I am unsure what you mean `(integer)` behind you `has_many` association

Comment: ah it worked. thx u sir :)